# Importing models into Gazebo Sim Gui "Milky" appearance

Tags: gazebo

Ubuntu 22.04/Gazebo Harmonic: Following https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/fuel_insert, 1) Spawn from 'Fuel Resource' using the Resource Spawner plugin: Why does the selected model from the openrobotics resource have a milky appearance, unlike the bright color from any Spawned models that are listed in the /usr/share/gz/gz-sim8 folder, for example with **gz sim shapes.sdf**. If this world is saved , say ***my.sdf*** to a local location, running ***gz sim my.sdf*** opens the gui not spawning i.e showing the image, even though listed in the Entity Tree.